# ORM compatible with GSON

Tags: android, orm, realm, gson, objectbox

While starting a serious project I encountered a problem to find an ORM that will work the best with Retrofit+GSON when it comes to custom types and relations. ORM like ObjectBox and Realm can't be used with GSON cause of their own types used to create relations. It can work with ObjectBox but require TypeAdapter for every entity. So what can be the best solution in that situation? Is it better to use Room?

Comment: `ORM like ObjectBox and Realm` uh... those are not ORMs, maybe that is your problem?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce usually seen them referred as ORM, but it doesn't answer the question anyway

Comment: You may check out JDXA ORM for Android. JDXA can provide persistence for JSON objects in a local SQLite database. It is non-intrusive; works with POJOs and does not require annotations. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.